# Chapter font in TOC with package quotchap

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, bold, titletoc, quotchap

I cannot get the chapter titles (not the `label`) in bold and Large font in the TOC, while using `quotchap`. I get the `label` "Chapter" in a good font (using `titletoc`), but not the `title` which stays in the 12pt not bold.

Here is the code I tried, with `titletoc`. If you run it, the words "test1" "test2" "test3" are in 12pt, and I'd like them to be in bold and Large.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % acecnts
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % accents
    \usepackage{tocloft}% I tried tyo load this package also to ass a rule under chapter
    %************ TITLES  ***************************************
    \usepackage[grey]{quotchap}% For a nice grey number at each new chapter
    \usepackage{titlesec} %clash with quot?
    \usepackage{titletoc}%to modify toc format 
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries\Large\scshape}{\thesection}{0.7em}{}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}

    \titlecontents{chapter}% level to be modified
     [0pt]{\addvspace{1cm}}%
     {\textsc{\hspace{-1cm}\textbf{\begin{Large}chapitre \thecontentslabel: \end{Large}}}}% mise en forme du titre.\LARGE
     {\bfseries}% for star chapters
    {\hfill\contentspage}
     [\addvspace{.5pc}]% 

    \begin{document}
    %
    %
    \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\scshape\bfseries\Huge}% to modify chapterlabel

    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire}

    \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}% add "Page" upon page numbers
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{test1}
    \section{bla}
    \section{blo}
    \chapter{test2}
    \chapter{test3}
    \end{document}
```

Here the results, with "test1", "test2" and "test3" in normal and small font. I'd like them to be in the same font as "Chapter"
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caution: You shouldn't mix similar styling packages like [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) and [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft).

According to the [`titletoc` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf):

> ```
> \titlecontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above>}
>               {<before with label>}{<before without label>}
>               {<filler and page>}[<after>]
> ```
>
> Here:
>
> - `<section>` is the section name without backslash: part, chapter, section, etc. figure
>     and table are allowed, too. (The backlash is omitted because we are dealing with the
>     concept and not the `\part`, `\section`, etc. macros themselves. Furthermore, figure and
>     table are environments.)
> - `<above>` is code for the global formatting of the entry. Vertical material is allowed. At this point the value of `\thecontentslabel` (see below) is known which enables you to
>     take decisions depending on its value (with the help of the `ifthen` package). You may use
>     the `titlesec` `\filleft`, `\filright`, `\filcenter` and `\fillast` commands.
> - `<left>` even if bracketted is currently mandatory and it sets the left margin from the left page margin.
> - `<before with label>` is in horizontal mode and it will be used just before the entry title. As in `\titleformat`, the last command can take an argument with the title.
> - `<before without label>` is like the above if there is, well, no label.
> - `<filler and page>` is self explanatory. Fillers are created with the `\titlerule` command which is shared by that package and `titlesec`. However, when used in this context its behaviour changes a little to fit the needs of ToC leaders. You might prefer a `\hspace` instead.
> - And finally `<after>` is code following the entry for, say, vertical space.

The title is set within `<before with label>` (or `<before without label>` is using the starred version), and "the last command can take an argument with the title." So, we create `\chaptitlefont` that takes an argument and sets it in `\bfseries\Large`:

[image]

```
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\newcommand{\chaptitlefont}[1]{{\bfseries\Large #1}}
\titlecontents{chapter}% level to be modified
  [0pt]{\addvspace{1cm}}%
  {\textsc{\hspace{-1cm}\bfseries\Large chapitre \thecontentslabel:}~\chaptitlefont}% mise en forme du titre.\LARGE
  {\bfseries}% for star chapters
  {\hfill\contentspage}
  [\addvspace{.5pc}]%
```